# Display result of a user action in a different view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am new to App development. I am creating a Quiz App. How can I display result image of right/ wrong answer into another page (ViewController) ? I will be very thankful if someone can help me out.

At the moment it is showing image in same controller, but however the problem for me was that when result image is displaying after correct or wrong answer... it does not go back go to continue with Game...

1. Is there any way to to display Result (of wrong/right) image from other controller?
2. Or is there any code I can fix, like If the image of result just display for few seconds and then continue with game automatically?

Here is my current code:

```
#import "Game.h"

@interface Game ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *ImageView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *Randonimage;

@end

@implementation Game

    -(void)RightAnswer{

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    Results.hidden = NO;
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"];
    Randomimage.hidden = YES;  
}

-(void)WrongAnswer{

    LivesNumber = LivesNumber - 1;
    Lives.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", LivesNumber];
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;
    Results.hidden = NO;
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"wrong.png"];
    Randomimage.hidden = YES;

    if(LivesNumber ==0) {
    Results.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"gameover.png"];
        GameInProgress = NO;
```

Comment: do you want to open view controller only for showing image??

Comment: Yes, or may be if the result-image can display for few seconds on the same controller and then the game continue with next questions. Thanks

Comment: @Simi based on your last comment your question makes no sense. So what your asking for is how to place a view to hover over the screen for a few seconds and disappear, but what you've asked is effectively how to pass data between 2 viewControllers which has been asked on stackoverflow too many times to count. Please correct your question with a full explanation of what you are trying to achieve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how your app is structured, you should create a new view controller (e.g. `ResultViewController`) and push it on your navigation controller or display it as a modal view or in a modal navigation controller.

You should write some code in your `ResultViewController` to dismiss itself when, for example, the image itself or a button is tapped.

I assume "Game" is your main view controller, even if from your code is not clear what it is :)

ARC-based code follows (RightAnswer used to show the pattern, but it applies to WrongAnswer as well):

In Game.m

```
- (void)RightAnswer {

    ScoreNumber = ScoreNumber + 1;
    Score.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", ScoreNumber];
    Answer1.hidden = YES;
    Answer2.hidden = YES;
    Answer3.hidden = YES;
    QuestionText.hidden = YES;
    CategorySelected.hidden = YES;

    ResultViewController *vc = [[ResultViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil image:[UIImage imageNamed:@"right.png"]];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

In ResultViewController.h

```
@interface ResultViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

In ResultViewController.m (assuming your imageView property is properly linked in Interface Builder)

```
#import "ResultViewController.h"

@implementation ResultViewController {

    UIImage *_image;
}

- (instancetype)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil image:(UIImage *)image {

    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        _image = image;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

     [super viewDidLoad];
     self.imageView.image = _image;
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

     [super viewDidAppear:animated];
     [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(dismiss) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}

- (void)dismiss {

     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

@end
```

The above code pops the view controller 5 seconds after it's been displayed.

Do not forget to `#import "ResultViewController.h"` in `Game.m`.

Of course these pieces of code are just a stub and can be improved a lot, please comment if you need more specific advices.

Comment: Many Thanks for quick reply. Just one question if I want my result image to display only for few seconds and the game then to continue without pressing any button, how can I do that? Sorry if my questions are silly.

Comment: You're welcome. Please see my latest edit. And as far as I'm concerned, no questions are "silly" so you don't need to apologize!

Comment: @Simi please accept this answer if you have got the answer for your question.

Comment: Hi Andrea - Just need one help.. when I put that code into Game.m = ResultViewController *vc = [[ResultViewController alloc] ...  it shows minor error - Unknown type name... All other seem to be ok. Many Thanks

Comment: @Simi I edited the answer. In short: do not forget to `#import "ResultViewController.h"` in `Game.m` or the compiler will complain.

Comment: @ Andrea - could you please help me out in my other question. Many thanks http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21205733/quiz-app-code-to-move-to-the-next